# I need a clean, portable function or library to remove diacritics from a string in C

Tags: open-source, c

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695385/remove-accents-from-string-in-c) is outdated and not feasible. I need to do this for real.

For example:

```
RemoveDiacritics("áèfoo")
```

Output:

```
aefoo
```

It also needs to be open source so I can embed it directly into my program, and support ***all*** variants such as `Å å Ǻ ǻ Ḁ ḁ ẚ Ă ă Ặ ặ Ắ ắ Ằ ằ Ẳ ẳ Ẵ ẵ Ȃ ȃ Â â Ậ ậ Ấ ấ Ầ ầ Ẫ ẫ Ẩ ẩ Ả ả Ǎ ǎ Ⱥ ⱥ Ȧ ȧ Ǡ ǡ Ạ ạ Ä ä Ǟ ǟ À à Ȁ ȁ Á á Ā ā Ā̀ ā̀ Ã ã Ą ą Ą́ ą́ Ą̃ ą̃ A̲ a̲ ᶏ` because I'm preprocessing strings prior to filtering for bad words. Wouldn't want `ᶏᶊⱾhole` getting by.

Comment: If I can't, I'll have to not support non ASCII characters which foreign language speakers wouldn't be too happy about.